# What type of client id is used in oauth for verifying google sign in tokens?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth, google-signin

I have issues implementing android and ios google sign in and verifying the users on my backend server.

I have generated my ANDROID_CLIEN_ID, IOS_CLIENT_ID and WEB_CLIENT_ID on google cloud console and entered all the required data to have them work on my development setup.

In my react native app, I am using the "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin" npm package to handle google signin. I correctly set up the IOS and android apps.

I call the config function to set the CLIENT_IDs

```
//React native
GoogleSignin.configure({
  iosClientId: IOS_CLIENT_ID,
  webClientId: WEB_CLIENT_ID,
  offlineAccess: true,
});
```

When I press on the sign in button, the following function is called:

```
//React native
const googleSignIn = async () => {
    try {
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
      const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();

      if (userInfo.idToken) {

        loginGoogleMobileMutation({
          variables: {
            data: {
              token: userInfo.idToken as string,
            },
          },
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
    }
  };
```

On my backend server, this endpoint is called:

```
//Nodejs Backend server
//google-auth-library npm package
loginGoogleMobile: {
      type: LoginMobileType,
      args: { data: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(LoginGoogleMobileInput) } },
      resolve: async (_, args) => {
        try {

          const client = new OAuth2Client(process.env.WEB_CLIENT_ID, process.env.WEB_CLIENT_SECRET);

          //Test
          const decodedToken = jwt.decode(args.data.token, { complete: true });
          //@ts-ignore
          console.log(JSON.stringify(decodedToken?.payload?.aud, null, 2));
          //----
    
          const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
            idToken: args.data.token,
            audience: [
              process.env.IOS_CLIENT_ID as string,
              process.env.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID as string,
            ],
          });
          const payload = ticket.getPayload();
          if (!payload) {
            throw new Error("Failed to get payload");
          }

          //Register or login person 
          //...

            return {
              //return data ...
            };

        } catch (error) {
          throw handleCatchError(error);
        }
      },
    },
```

When I call this endpoint, i get the "Wrong recipient, payload audience != requiredAudience" error

Now, I am very confused about which CLIENT_ID goes where in the code, as the guides never mention the specific CLIENT_ID, and I am further confused about the client id that is sent to my endpoint.

I would expect that I need to put WEB_CLIENT_ID and WEB_CLIENT_SECRET inside my `OAuth2Client()` function, and in the `verifyIdToken`, under audience to put ANDROID_CLIENT_ID and IOS_CLIENT_ID, as those are the only platforms that I'm using the google sign in on.

When I further inspect the decoded token before verification:

```
const decodedToken = jwt.decode(args.data.token, { complete: true });
```

Both iOS and android are sending the WEB_CLIENT_ID as "aud" instead of their respective IOS or ANDROID CLIENT_ID. What is further confusing is if i put IOS_CLIENT_ID inside `OAuth2Client`, and ANDROID and WEB CLIENT_ID inside `verifyIdToken` audience, both android and ios apps are performing a successful validation on my server.

Can someone please explain how do those client Ids work, and where do I need to put them in my server-side code?

Note: I am not using firebase.